# How to query recent comments in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

The the post document looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  comments: [{
    _id:...
    body:...
    createDate:...
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

How do I get recent 10 comments from the collection?

Comment: Based on your comments below, you should update your question to describe your requirements more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your comments are always in a predictable order (i.e. newest first, or newest last), then you can use the `$slice` operator to return just a subset of the full `comments` field when querying:

```
test> db.foo.save({name: "hello", comments: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
test> db.foo.find({}, {comments: {$slice: 3}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ec7d1c8e72da9b6f31e2528"), "name" : "hello", "comments" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
test> db.foo.find({}, {comments: {$slice: -3}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ec7d1c8e72da9b6f31e2528"), "name" : "hello", "comments" : [ 3, 4, 5 ] }
```

You can read more about controlling the returned fields at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields

Comment: I mean getting recent comments from the whole documents in the collection not just from the single document.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, you might need to model your data differently, as @RameshVel suggests, or you could use Map-Reduce to extract the comments into a separate collection and query that.

Comment: This is very common use-case like showing recent comments on the blog. I'm starting to miss relational database :(

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to partially select the items from embedded document. No matter what it will return the entire array of document. You have to do the filter in your application code. Thats the only way.

But i recommend to have a separate collection for comments. That way you can skip & limit the set.

Comment: -1 You can use the `$slice` operator to retrieve a specific subset of embedded documents within an array, and normal field selection to return a specific set of non-array embedded documents.

Comment: oh my bad.. i missed that one :(